# imageview from URI catch file not found

Tags: android, imageview, uri, firebase-storage

```
imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl2);
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(c.getPhotoUrl())));
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // handle errors
                Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // handle errors
                Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "Error : "+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

the URI is jpeg file I'm trying decode it into bitmap
and it keeps catching file not found

Comment: the method you are following is not actually a good approach. try using async task or using image download libraries like picasso, glide etc.

Comment: Please check you receive image or not ? Use `Picasso` library.

Comment: first check url on your browser that image exists or not

Comment: ok i'll try using Picasso